# How to use local html5 storage to save grid preferences in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, local-storage, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My grid is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Stuff>()
.Name("Grid")
    .DataSource(source => source.Ajax().Events(events=>events.Error("onError"))
    .Events(events=>events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
    .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Field(p => p.PurchaseQuantity).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.PurchasePrice).Editable(false);
        })
    .Read("GetData", "Data"))
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.PurchaseQuantity).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.PurchasePrice).Format("{0:C}").Width(100);

    })
.Sortable()
.Pageable(page=> page.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }).Refresh(true))
.Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(false))
.Events(boo=>boo.DataBound("onTest"))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:850px" })
```

)

and the javascript used to load data is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var storage = window.localStorage;
var storageLoaded = false;

function onError() {
    $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.cancelChanges();
}
function onTest() {
    if (!storageLoaded) {
        console.log('loading size from storage ' + storage.pageSize);
        storageLoaded = true;
        console.log('marked storage loaded');
        $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize(storage.PageSize);
        console.log('set pagesize from storage ' + storage.pageSize);
        var pagesize = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize();
        console.log('page size is ' + pagesize);
    }
}

function onRequestEnd(e) {
    if (storageLoaded) {
        var pagesize = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize();
        storage.pageSize = pagesize;
        console.log('setting size to storage ' + storage.pageSize);
    }
}
```

---

firebug console shows:

loading size from storage 50 / marked storage loaded / set pagesize from storage 50 / page size is 10

Questions:
Why does the pagesize not save after set?
Is there a better way to accomplish this?
Is there a way to attach to the pagesize selector instead of using requestEnd?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Make the grid `.AutoBind(false)`

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    storageLoaded = true;
    $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._pageSize = storage.pageSize;
    $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
});
```

now this is making use of an _ variable inside the datasource which could break at any point in the future, but for now it does work.

I removed the databound event completely, a friend at Telerik was most helpful in getting me to the solution.

Hoping that in the future there will be something like:

`.Pageable(page=> page.PageSizes(true).Refresh(true).Sticky("gridPageSizeDefault")`

which will store the value in html5 local storage using the `gridPageSizeDefaultkey`.